# objective-c spawn many monsters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, 2d

I made a little iPhone game but now I wanted to make multiple monsters to spawn. So I have one UIImageView called enemy that spawns at beginning of the game. But I want it to spawn many more monsters until I say it needs to stop spawning them. I know how to get random locations.
I don't want to add like 20 other enemy's and 20 image views and give them all the same function i jus twang to declare one image view called enemy but that image spawns many times.

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Each enemy will likely need its own coordinates, position, hitpoints, spellpoints, etc. So the obvious solution would be to have something like a MonsterTracker class that has an array of Monster objects that you expand to the number of instances you need.

Comment: okay i will look over that but how do i implement that class into my game

Answer (score 0):

Create a monster factory using the factory pattern.  Here's an obj-c [example](http://www.howtomakeiphoneapps.com/how-to-implement-a-factory-pattern-in-iphone-code/116/).